# Need help scanning the contents of a file into an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, input

I need to read in a file, each line of the file has one string on it (max 50 char long) and i need to store each line into an array of pointers. So if the file reads:

```
1234
abcd
5667
...
```

Then the array (called functions) would be *functions[0] = 1234, *functions[1]= abcd and so on...

I've tried a few things now and i can't quite seem to get it to work. This is the start of my code, or at least the parts pertaining to my confusion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 201            /* 200 is th emax number of lines in the file*/
#define MAX_FUNCTION_LENGTH 51    /* each line is at ax 50 characters long

main() {
    char func[MAX_FUNCTION_LENGTH]
    char * functions[MAX_SIZE]      /* this is my ragged array*/    
    FILE * inf;
    inf =fopen("list.txt", "r");
```

I've tried a few things but I can't manage to make *functions store the values properly. Can someone help me out? :)

Comment: Did you try initializing with with malloc()?

Comment: yeha I've tried doing that, the problem is that i usually just end up filling every pointer with either the last or first line depending on the method i use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 201

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    FILE *fp = fopen ( "D:\\personal\\input.txt","r");
    if ( !fp )
        exit ( -1 );
    char line [50];
    char *functions[MAX_SIZE];
    int index = 0;
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fgets (line , 50 , fp);
        functions[index++] = strdup (line);
    }
    fclose ( fp );
    for ( int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        printf ( "[%d] -> [%s]\n", i, functions[i]);
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
           free ( functions[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: `strdup` is non-standard (though simple enough to implement) and also requires `free`ing when the data is no longer needed (which the OP seems to be wanting to avoid.)

Comment: well this works, my thanks. Might need some help with the freeing as Chris said though, how do i do this?